# ArrayList en Java, comprobar si el ArrayList está lleno o no

Tags: java, arraylist, pilas

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio de crear una pila usando arrayList, tengo el siguiente código para indicar si el arrayList está **vacío** o no

```
else if(opcion==4){
            if(pila2.size()==0){
                System.out.println("La pila está vacía");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("La pila no está vacía");
            }

        }
```

Está en un Do while porque el ejercicio es crear un menú con distintas opciones, de ahí la primera línea, la opción 4 es saber si mi Arraylist está vacío o no, creo que es correcto. La pregunta que tengo ahora sería la opción que viene a continuación, la 5, que sería justo lo contrario, mostrar si el arraylist está lleno o no. ¿Cómo podría plantearlo? Llevo un rato dándole vueltas y no consigo sacarlo. Gracias.

Comment: Si **pila2** es un ArrayList se puede usar el método isEmpty() que retorna true si no contiene elementos -> *pila2.isEmpty();*  en el caso 5 simplemente tenes que negar el resultado con **!**   -> * ! pila2.isEmpty()*;

Comment: Gracias, solucionado, no conocía el .isEmpty

Comment: Agregué lo mencionado en el comentario anterior en forma de respuesta  para seguir las reglas de la comunidad SOEsp. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para un ArrayList (u otra colección que implemente List) existe el método isEmpty() que retorna true si el mismo no contiene elementos.

Se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
pila2.isEmpty()
```

Para el caso 5 "saber si la pila tiene algún elemento es decir, no es vacía" . Puedes negar el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
!pila2.isEmpty()
```

así la evaluación genera los siguientes resultados:

- si  está vacío -> true  -> y negado es false
- si no es vacío -> false -> y negado es true

  ```
   if( !pila2.isEmpty() ){
       System.out.println("La pila tiene elementos");
   } else {
       System.out.println("La pila no tiene elementos");
   }
  ```

Si no quieres utilizar la negación, puedes cambiar de lugar tus mensajes, aunque no es exactamente lo que estas buscando: 'si la pila tiene algún elemento'.

Por último, un ArrayList nunca está 'lleno', siempre crece en tamaño para aceptar nuevos elementos, la única limitación es la memoria disponible.